# Saving Photo in Image View to Parse Object in Android

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I am trying to add an image file to an object in parse, and I need help about it.

I try the code below,  but in the "getBytes()" part I got the error "cannot resolve method. How Can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

```
profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.signup_activity_imgView);
profileImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
profileImage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = profileImage.getDrawingCache();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


byte[] data = byteArray.getBytes();

ParseFile image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.jpg", data);

userSettingObj.put("photo", image1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getBytes()` is a method of `String` class and you trying to call on `byte[]`

```
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
byte[] data = byteArray.getBytes();
```

Apparently you'll not able to call this method on `byte[]`

Comment: Hello Shadab, how can I save the image file to parse?

Comment: Why don't you change this line ParseFile image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.jpg", data);  to ParseFile image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.jpg", byteArray); ?